# Wordpress custom widgets shows in wrong position

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I want to display a contact-widget in my custom Wordpress theme, so I placed it in a shortcode so I can call it any time and any place. The problem is that the shortcode shows on top of the original  I placed the shortcode in. This happens with widgets, normal text-fields etc.

First I added the line
`add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );`
to enable the fields for showing shortcodes.

In my functions.php I placed the following code where I call a template part with the contact information. I saw another topic where they solved the problem by `return`'ing a variable.

```
    // contact widget
function contact_info_shortcode() { 
    
    $contact = get_template_part('includes/sections/contact', 'info');
    
    return $contact;

    } 
add_shortcode('contact_info', 'contact_info_shortcode');
```

In that code I call the following template file that shows my contact information

```
    <?php

    $contact_title = get_field('contact-titel', 'option');
    $phone = get_field('telefoon', 'option');
    $email = get_field('e-mail', 'option');
    $adress = get_field('adres', 'option');
    $place = get_field('plaats', 'option');
;?>
```

```
<table class="contact-table">

    <!-- telefoon -->
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></td>
        <td><a class="contact-info-link" href="<?php echo $phone['url'];?>" target="<?php echo $phone['target'];?>"><?php echo $phone['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- email -->
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></td>
        <td><a class="contact-info-link" href="<?php echo $email['url'];?>" target="<?php echo $email['target'];?>"><?php echo $email['title'];?></a></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- adres -->
    <tr>
        <td><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></td>
        <td>
            <p class="contact-info-adress"><?php echo $adress;?></p>
            <p class="contact-info-adress"><?php echo $place;?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Hope you guys know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `get_template_part()` is really just a wrapper for an include, which is essentially `echoing` the template part, so you can't assign it to a variable.

What you need to do is hold the template part in an `output buffer` and then return the output buffer.

```
function contact_info_shortcode() { 
    // Here we start the output buffer.
    ob_start();
    // This is now held in the output buffer.
    get_template_part('includes/sections/contact', 'info');
    // Now we can return the data in the output buffer.
    return ob_get_clean();
} 
add_shortcode('contact_info', 'contact_info_shortcode');
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my problem!

Comment: @RicardiodePenning if this solves the issue, then please upvote and mark this answer as accepted.